# Minesweeper program in C trouble with numbers surrounding mines

Tags: c, minesweeper

So I need to write a program that creates the grid like in minesweeper, and then you input how many mines you want, and then the location of the mines. My program so far seems to work fine until I decide to put a mine on the same row as another mine. When I put a second mine on the same row, the numbers that are supposed to be adjacent to the mine that show how many mines are adjacent to it doesn't always work. Here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

It also seems like the numbers are carrying over from the far right side of the grid and going to the left side- (I think that is why there is that lone "1" that isn't adjacent to a mine on the left of the grid)?

here is what my code looks like for this minesweeper program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int N;
    int M;
    int W;
    int x;
    int y;

    printf("Enter your rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    scanf("%d", &M);

    int grid[N][M];
    int i;
    int j;

    for( i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    printf("enter number of mines");
    scanf("%d", &W);

    for(i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        printf("enter location of mines");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        scanf("%d", &y);

        grid[x][y]=-100;

        if(x>0 && y>0)
            grid[x-1][y-1]++;
        if(x>0)
            grid[x-1][y]++;
        if(x>0 && y+1<M)
            grid[x-1][y+1]++;
        if(y>0)
            grid[x][y+1]++;
        if(y+1<M)
            grid[x][y-1]++;
        if(x+1<N && y>0)
            grid[x+1][y-1]++;
        if(x+1<N )
            grid[x+1][y]++;
        if(x+1<N && y+1<M)
            grid[x+1][y+1]++;
    }


    for(i = 0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j =0;j<M;j++)
        {
            if(grid[i][j]<0)
                printf("* ");
            else
                printf("%d ",grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: It seems to me that you mixed up `y-1` and `y+1` in the cases `if(y>0)` and `if(y+1<M)` ...

Comment: Thanks both of y'all! I had switched up the y-1 and y+1 like you said. Thanks again!